# Downloading files from a server and put it to /raw folder

Tags: java, android

Here is I want to make. I want to make an app, for example it has a button that will download a certain video file and put it on the resource(raw) folder. Is it possible?

Comment: You can't make change in raw folder once apk in build

Comment: No you cant, save it in sd card of your mobile apps folder once you download

Comment: oh ok sir. how the "downloading contents" in games work? because I dont know what search term will I put in google. Im so noob.

Comment: can I hide that folder in sd programatically? so that it can't access in the gallery? Im sorry im so noob in android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer : You can not**.

You can not, under any circumstance, write/dump a file to the raw/assets folder in runtime.

What you can do is to download the video and store it into **Internal Memory** (application reserved storage) **or External Memory** (usually your SDCard))

For example, you can store media files, for instance a Bitmap to your external storage like this.

```
 private void saveAnImageToExternalMemory(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
    myDir.mkdirs();
    String fname = "yourimagename.jpg";
    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And equally, read an file, in this example an image (which is then loaded to an imageView), from external memory

```
private void loadImageFromStorage(String path){
    try {
        File f=new File(path, "profile.jpg");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgPicker);
        img.setImageBitmap(b);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

**Edit**: Additionally, you can store your data into internal memory

> Alternatively you can also save the Bitmap to the internal storage in
>   case the SD card is not available or for whatever other reasons you
>   may have. Files saved to the internal storage are only accessible by
>   the application which saved the files. Neither the user nor other
>   applications can access those files

```
public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("yourimage.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Check this documentation for more information](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Regards,

Comment: can i make the directory hidden? because i dont want to make the files viewable in the gallery of the phone.

Comment: Yes, you can. You can, instead of storing it to externalMemory (sdcard), store the data to the internal application storage. Check my editted response

Answer (score 0):

You can use android sqlite database to manage your download file.